# How to access localhost service with http proxy on docker network

Tags: docker, http-proxy, docker-network

So I have a setup with a react service running in a docker-compose service and on a network in that compose. For that react service I use the [http-proxy-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware) to be able to just use relative endpoints (/api/... instead of localhost:xxxx/api/...) both in development and in production but also because one of the libraries that I depend on requires it (for the same reason).

I also have a python flask backend that I want to run on the localhost network to be able to avoid restarting the entire docker-compose on every change.

Currently, the proxy (as expected I suppose) gives a "ECONNREFUSED" error when used as it cannot connect to the backend.

Does anyone have an idea of how I could get the proxy to be able to access the backend without having to run the backend in the docker-compose?

Thanks in advance, Vidar

Comment: Regarding running the python flask backend, can you not simply run it in hot reload mode, in which case, the flask server would "recompile" itself once a change was detected?

Comment: I was not aware that that was even a thing, after a bit of googling I'm gonna give it a go, thank you @Hikash.

However I do see one issue with that and that is that that wouldn't work with the IDE debugger. :/

Comment: I think that's correct. Since you're in python, you can still use pdb, at least. For what it's worth, I think you _should_ be able to get your docker-compose frontend to talk to your local backend, but I think you need to treat your local backend as a remote server, and I imagine you need to tell the frontend what ip (i.e. not loopback) or domain, is needed. You may also need to change flask to serve on 0.0.0.0, if you aren't already.

Answer (score 1):

So I finally got it working, with help from @Hikash, by setting my frontend proxy to connect to the localhost through the IP I get from `ip -4 addr show docker0 | grep -Po 'inet \K[\d.]+'`.